# How to set pan in IOS Audio Unit Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, audio-streaming

Hello stack overflow users,

i want to change pan position using UISlided in my IOS application.

i am upgrading whole app which is currently using **AudioStreamer** of **Matt Gallagher**

To change the pan value in in AudioStreamer used below code.

AudioQueueRef audioQueue; // defined in AudioStreamer.h file

```
    - (void)changePan:(float)newPan
{
    OSStatus panErr = AudioQueueSetParameter( audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Pan, newPan);
    NSLog(@" setting pan: %ld", panErr);
    if( panErr )
        NSLog(@"Error setting pan: %ld", panErr);
}
```

i am replacing AudioStreamer with StreamingKit which use AudioUnit

if i will get some help to make this thing done using StreamingKit or AudioUnit i will appreciate that.

P.S Let me know if anyone needs more info.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using AudioUnit API, you can simply set the `kMultiChannelMixerParam_Pan` property of the audio mixer unit to set the stereo pan:

```
AudioUnitParameterValue panValue = 0.9; // panned almost dead-right. possible values are between -1 and 1
int result = AudioUnitSetParameter(mixerUnit, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Pan, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, panValue, 0);
if (result == 0)
{
   NSLog("success");
}
```

You may also need to retrieve the internal `mixerUnit` instance variable from inside `STKAudioPlayer`. You can try `[audioPlayer valueForKey:@"_mixerUnit"]` for that or implement a getter yourself inside StreamingKit's files.